# Overfull \hbox error on begin

Tags: boxes

I get the following error when I try to build my document:

> Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 32--32
>   []

line 34 is

```
\begin{document}
```

The other questions about overfull error say it's because the line is too long, but how can the begin line be too long?

Comment: Please edt your question so that it includes a complete document that reproduces the problem. Without that, it's probably going to be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: The suggestion to add a compilable example is important, but I'm guessing that something in your preamble or a loaded package specifies `AtBeginDocument`, and that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: the log file shows _which_ file the bad line 34 is in and it also (usually) gives an indication of the text that is over full, but as you have neither shown the input nor the log, it is hard to help.

Comment: Sorry I messed up and copied the line instead of the error.

Comment: I don't sees anything that says AtBeginDocument. The document itself contains info I can't post and the example I tried to make doesn't have the error.

Comment: between \document class[options](page type} and \begin{document} you have **to us** an unknown number of packages, definitions etc. we cannot "with the best will in the world" know what you added before the document starts compiling that makes pages too narrow or textline too wide. So you need to remove those parts of that preamble that do not start the exact overfull by 30pt message. equally we do not want to see tons of private content just the first few lines with dummy content that create EXACTLY the same error. That then is an MWE (in reality a Minimal nonWorking  Extract) so we can test

Comment: If you really have an overfull box from the text at line 34 you can delete everything after that and produce a document you can post. However as it is a round figure like 30pt it will not be text you afre presumably adding an image or minipage that is exactly 30pt wider than the space where it is being added. Is the \parindent set to 30pt?

Comment: I saved a copy of the file with a different name intending to remove the personal data and post it, but it compiled just fine before I made any changes. This leaves me confused but at least I've got my document updated. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Glad you got something working but I voted to close this question (or you could delete it) as it is impossible to answer unless it is edited to provide some information.